# How to T-SQL GROUP BY using another GROUP BY

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

[image: SQL_GroupByQry]

I have following T-SQL query:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN ap.Brand = 'T' THEN 'Toyota'
    WHEN ap.BRAND = 'L' THEN 'Lexus'
    ELSE 'Both'
END AS Brand, av.Name, YEAR(ap.Last_update_date) AS YEAR, MONTH(ap.Last_update_date) AS MONTH, COUNT(an.Id) AS COUNT FROM AimNotifications an
INNER JOIN AIM_PUBS ap ON ap.GUID = an.Publication_Id
INNER JOIN AIM_PUB_X_VEHICLE apv ON apv.AIM_PUB_ID = ap.GUID
INNER JOIN AIM_VEHICLES av on apv.VEHICLE_ID = av.Id
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, ap.Last_update_date) = 4
GROUP BY av.Name, an.Id, YEAR(ap.Last_update_date), MONTH(ap.Last_update_date), ap.Brand
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 4 DESC, 2 ASC, 1 DESC
```

This gives me the results shown in the attached picture.
But I still need to do another GROUP BY for the identical records (e.g.: like the first 7 records).

Comment: The ```an.Id``` seems messy in your GROUP BY statement

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(op.Brand) = MIN(ap.Brand) THEN MAX(ap.Brand) ELSE 'Both' END) as brand,
       av.Name, YEAR(ap.Last_update_date) AS YEAR, MONTH(ap.Last_update_date) AS MONTH, 
      COUNT(an.Id) AS COUNT
FROM AimNotifications an JOIN
     AIM_PUBS ap
     ON ap.GUID = an.Publication_Id JOIN
     AIM_PUB_X_VEHICLE apv
     ON apv.AIM_PUB_ID = ap.GUID JOIN
     AIM_VEHICLES av 
     ON apv.VEHICLE_ID = av.Id
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, ap.Last_update_date) = 4 AND
      AP.Brand IN ('L', 'T')
GROUP BY av.Name, YEAR(ap.Last_update_date), MONTH(ap.Last_update_date)
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 4 DESC, 2 ASC, 1 DESC;
```

This fixes your query directly, without another level of aggregation.

Notes:

- Filtering on the month without the year is suspicious, but I didn't change that.
- Removes `Brand` from the `GROUP BY`.
- Removes `id` from the `GROUP BY`.
- Adds logic for `Brand` so you can get "Both".
- Filters only on `'L'` and `'T'` -- may not be necessary if those are the only brands in your data.

Comment: GENIUS! Thnx a lot!

Comment: Yes, I filtered on month; just to have less results to work with. But 'BOTH' should also be in the query.
I only have to still figure out how to 'CASE' it back again from T to Toyota and L to Lexus...